# Django allauth, authenticated user, multiple sessions

Tags: python, django, session, oauth, django-allauth

I implemented a custom OAuth adapter using Django-allauth, in order to start from an existing codebase (this is a Django 1.9 project). The idea is that my django users are authenticated through the Authorization Code flow. The Oauth flow is working fine, and I can log in properly into my django app.

I have a weird problem with sessions and having multiple sessions for one user and I'm trying to track down a specific behaviour either from Django or Django-allauth. For some reason each user can only have one active session at a time and it's bothering me because I don't know at which point is the original session invalidated/flushed and I have nothing in place to logout users in the first place.

This is what I do:
* I log into my django app using the OAuth Authorization Code flow in browser A, access a resource, modify it. When I refresh browser A I'm still logged in and my modifications are saved.
* I log into my django app using the OAuth Authorization Code flow in browser B, I access the same resource (loading the modifications I did on browser A), modify it. When I refresh browser B I'm still logged in and my modifications are saved. (So at this point everything is happening as expected)
* Now I refresh browser A. What I would expect would be that I'm still logged in, as I have literally no logout support and in my tests the session doesn't expire for quite a while. I should be able to refresh, still be logged, and see whatever I did on browser B. But for some reason, I'm logged out (request user is AnonymousUser), and the session has been completely flushed at some point (but when?).

I've set up logs on the user_logged_in and user_logged_out signals as well as on my OAuth flow, and from what I can tell, user_logged_out is never sent (and anyway the django logout should not invalidate every other session related to the user, shouldn't it?). There doesn't seem to be any request.session.flush() anywhere within the django-allauth code.

It may be that I'm missing a fundamental point in Django-allauth or even Django itself, I don't know.

Does anyone have any idea about this?

Comment: django-allauth are deprecated and will have many incompatibilities with the lastest django versions, use python-social-auth instead.

Comment: can you provide us with a link of reference? i see recent commits and releases in the repo and no mention of deprecation there or in the docs.